# Can't Send message in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I am developing woman safety app.I want to send the user location via  message using SmsManager  when the user shake their phone. I have two mobile phone operators in my country,

> Orredo

and

> Telenor

for sending message.When I use

> Orredo,I can send message but when I use
> Telenor, I can't send message.I want to know what cause the problem is.Because of my code or my mobile phone operator??.

Here is my code.
My code may be a little messy and make no sense because I am beginner and I developed this app from scratch.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (broadcastReceiver == null) {
            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                        tv1.append(""+intent.getExtras().get("Coordinate"));
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GPS_Service.class);
                        stopService(intent1);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: "+tv1.getText());



                }
            };
        }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_update"));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (broadcastReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }


    private void enable_buttons() {
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    private final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

            acelLast = acelVal;
            acelVal = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x + y * y + z * z));
            float delta = acelVal - acelLast;
            shake = shake * 0.9f + delta;


            if (shake > 12) {
                mDatbaseHelper =new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                Cursor data = mDatbaseHelper.getData();
                while (data.moveToNext()) {
                    phone1 = data.getString(1);
                    phone2 = data.getString(2);
                }

                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")

                String s = "tel:" + phone1;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(s));
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    return;
                }
                startActivity(intent);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_CODE);




                if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                   smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone1, null,"google.com/maps/place/"+tv1.getText().toString(), null, null);
                   Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChange: "+tv1.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
```

And here is my code for GPS Service.

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {
    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    public static final String TAG ="GPS_Service";


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                i.putExtra("Coordinate", location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
//                i.putExtra("Latitude", location.getLatitude());
//                i.putExtra("Longitude", location.getLongitude());
                sendBroadcast(i);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }


        };
        locationManager =(LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,listener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(locationManager!=null)
        {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: @blackapps Bro I mean mobile phone operators.The message I want to send is user location by using background location service . The background location service is received by broadcastReceiver in my app. I just can't understand why one Operator can send the message while another Operator can't.

Comment: @blackapps Sorry for my unclear Question Bro.Now I edit my question and add my GPS Service code. I want to receive user Coordinates that is Longitude and Latitude in my onReceive and send that Coordinates using Sms Manager.

Comment: And you want that sms to be send by Android Studio when you are with your Android device in town? Why are you not mentioning sms in the subject of your post? Why isnt there an `sms` tag? Why dont you mention an sms message in the first line of your post? And why are you still only talking about operators instead of  mobile phone operators (which are only known in your country) ? I try for seven hours now to let you write a better post....

Comment: @blackapps Really Sorry for my bad question and for wasting your time.Next time I will try to write better and more understanding question.And now for this question,maybe my error is because of my country mobile phone operators problem or maybe I am wrong at some point in my codes.

Comment: @blackapps Ok bro .I try my best editing to better understand the question.

Comment: Ok. Then now adapt the subject as you should mention sms and remove Android Studio. I asked that before. Oh.. this takes so much time... You cant send an sms message with your Android device for some operator.

Comment: @blackapps. I see bro.Today I got another mobile phone operator sim card and tried with that sim  and it worked out.That mean the problem is  because of that one exceptional mobile phone operator of my country.Thank you for your suggestions and afford bro.